# How do I make my custom select menu occupy the entire screen for small screen widths?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, mobile, html-lists

I'm using jQuery 1.12.  I have created a stylized select mneu (using ULs and LIs) by taking a regular SELECT menu, applying the below styles

```
.select-options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #737373;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.select-options li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #676767;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

.select-options li.selected {
  color: gray;
  background: #fff;
}

.select-options li[rel="hide"] {
  display: none;
}


ul.select-options {
  max-height: 15em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and using the JS

```
function styleSelectMenu(selectMenu)
{
    var $this = $(selectMenu), numberOfOptions = $(selectMenu).children('option').length;

        /*** NEW - start ***/
        var $paddingCalculator = $('<div />', {
            'class' : "select-styled test"
    }).css({
            width : 0,
        visibility : "hidden"
    }).appendTo("body");
    $this.addClass('select-hidden');
    var paddingWidth = $paddingCalculator.outerWidth() + 10;
    $paddingCalculator.remove();

    var selectWidth = $this.outerWidth() + paddingWidth;
    var clickHandled = false;

    if ( !$this.parent().hasClass('select') ) {
            var $wrapper = $("<div />", {
                'class' : "select", 
            'tabIndex' : '1' 
        }).css({
                width   : selectWidth
        }).focus(function() {
        $(this).find('.select-styled').click(); 
    }).blur(function() {
        clickHandled = false;
            $(this).find(".select-options li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).find('.select-styled').removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide(); 
    });
        $this.wrap( $wrapper );
    }   // if

    if ( !$this.next().hasClass('select-styled') ) {
        $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');
    }    // if

    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    if ( $styledSelect.parent().find('ul').length > 0 ) {
        $styledSelect.parent().find('ul').remove();
    }   // if
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'select-options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    // This is the event when someone opens the list
    $styledSelect.unbind('click')
    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
    //if(clickHandled) {  
        //    clickHandled = false; 
        //} else {
            clickHandled = true;
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('div.select-styled.active').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
            });
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
            var selectedIndex = $(this).parent().find('select option:selected').index();         
            selectedElement = $(this).parent().find(".select-options li")[selectedIndex];
            $(selectedElement).addClass("selected"); 
            selectedElement.scrollIntoView(false); 
        //} // if 
    });

    // This is the event when someone actually selects something from the list
    $listItems.unbind('click.selectStyledItem')
    $listItems.bind('click.selectStyledItem', function(event) {
         clickListItem(event, $styledSelect, $this, $(this), $list);
    });

    $(document).click(function(event) {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

    var selectedIndex = $this[0].selectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex > 0) {
        var name = $this.attr("name")
        var selectedText = $( "select[name='" + name + "'] option:selected" ).text();
        selectItemFromStyledList($styledSelect, $this, selectedText, $list);
    }   // if

    var parent = $this.parent()
    $(parent).bind('keydown', function(event) {
        var currentElement = $(this).find(".select-options li.selected");
        if (currentElement.length == 0) {
            currentElement = $(this).find(".select-options li")[0];
            $(currentElement).addClass("selected");
            return;
        }       // if
        var nextElement;
        switch(event.keyCode){
        // case up
        case 38:
            nextElement = $(this).find(".select-options li")[($(this).find(".select-options li").index(currentElement) - 1) % $(this).find(".select-options li").length];
            break;
    // case down 
        case 40:
            nextElement = $(this).find(".select-options li")[($(this).find(".select-options li").index(currentElement) + 1) % $(this).find(".select-options li").length];
            break;
    // case <ENTER>
        case 13:
            var currentElement = $(this).find(".select-options li.selected");
            $(currentElement).click(); 
            break;
    // case escape 
    case 27:
        $(this).blur(); 
        }
        $(this).find(".select-options li").removeClass("selected");
        if(nextElement) {
            $(nextElement).addClass("selected");
        nextElement.scrollIntoView(false); 
        }
    });

    var keyUps = "", timeOut, $selectOptions = $('.select-options'); 
    $(parent).bind('keyup', function(event) {
    if(!$selectOptions.prev().hasClass('active')){
            return false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode){
        keyUps += event.key;
        retrieveFromOptions($selectOptions,keyUps);
    }
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        keyUps = "";
    },250); 
    });

    $listItems.hover(
    function(e) {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    },
    function(e) {
        $(this).closest(".select-options").find("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
    }
    );

}
```

This is a Fiddle that illustrates [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p5148dfr/2/) .  my question is, for mobile browsers (e.g. screen width <= 500), how do I make my customized menu occupy the entire screen when someone clicks on it -- that is, the first element would appear at coordinates zero, zero and the width of each LI element would occupy the entire width of the screen?  I'm basically tryihng to simulate how a regular SELECT menu behaves on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:501px) {
  .active,
  .active + ul {
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: initial;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
}
```

<strike>[Old JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/p5148dfr/3/)</strike>

**Update**:  Try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/p5148dfr/4/). Okay, it's a little hard to read your code, but I think that line 35 is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for this update.  On Mac Chrome, when I compress the screen and click on the menu for the first time, it doesn't stay open.  It does manage to stay open the second time I click it, but is there any way to make it such that the menu stays open the first time I click it?  I don't see this behavior on Mac Firefox.

Comment: THnaks but I'm still not getting the menu to open the first time I click on it.  I compress the screen width to less than 500px and then click the menu on Mac Chrome but it closes immediately as opposed to staying open.

Comment: THat's a winner!  Thanks